# Jmeter Execution on Remote system does not work

Tags: jmeter, command-line-arguments

I am able to successfully execute JMX file on local instance but execution on Remote system(Slaves) fails. I am using latest version of Jmeter. This is the second time I am facing the issue.

Can you please advise if I am missing anything here. I initially thought it was because I had toggled off the script from Execution but thats not the case here.

My script(JMX) has a Transaction controller(under a Thread group) with some http requests.

Code from command line executed is as below. Its the same result when I execute from Run>>Remote Start

sh Jmeter.sh -n -t R3Performance_Fragment.jmx -R 192.168.7.25 -G ucount=1  -l Results/r1.csv

Results are as below. It just starts and winds up without initiating the Execution at all.

> Krishna-MBP:bin krishnap$ sh Jmeter.sh -n -t
>   R3Performance_Fragment.jmx -R 192.168.7.25 -G ucount=1  -l
>   Results/r1.csv Creating summariser  Created the tree
>   successfully using R3Performance_Fragment.jmx Configuring remote
>   engine: 192.168.7.25 Starting remote engines Starting the test @ Mon
>   May 29 13:07:40 IST 2017 (1496043460922) Remote engines have been
>   started Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on
>   port 4446 summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min:
>   9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
>   Tidying up remote @ Mon May 29 13:07:43 IST 2017 (1496043463653) ...
>   end of run

Answer (score 1):

Check the .jmx file you uploaded. If you are using any .csv file. Need to change the location of it. It will be pointing to your local machine. Change it to remote machines address

Answer (score 0):

The answer is always in *jmeter.log* file:

- Look into *jmeter.log* file on **master** for any suspicious entries
- Run JMeter slave instance(s) like:

  > jmeter ${RMI_HOST_DEF} -Dserver_port=${SERVER_PORT:-1099} -s -j jmeter-server.log -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Dserver_port=xxxx -s **-j jmeter-server.log**

  Look into *jmeter-server.log* file on remote slave(s)

Most likely your test fragment configuration is not correct. JMeter is not smart enough to copy dependencies (external .jmx files) automatically, you should copy it to all remote slave(s) manually prior to starting the test. The same applies to i.e. CSV configuration files, files you will be uploading, etc. Other reasons could be in:

- 0 threads (virtual users)
- disabled thread group/transaction controller
- incorrect test fragment reference

See the following guides for more information:

- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)
- [How to Manage Large JMeter Scripts With JMeter Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments)

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs, this should set the direction for me to further analyze